# Facebook Inbox Custom Label API unable to search for labels I set

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to programmatically assign inbox labels to users so that humans can follow up with them. I am assigning the labels through the GET /CUSTOM_LABEL_ID/label endpoint and getting back success:true. When I look at the user on the left in the messages folder, I see the label assigned but when I click on them I don't see it in the list of labels on the right. When I try to search inbox with that label as a filter, the user doesn't appear. In addition, if I create a new label through the POST /custom_labels endpoint, I don't see it under *Manage Labels* even though the response says the call was successful. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/custom-labels, it seems there should be no difference between using the graph api call and the Fb page inbox app to make the change.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open bug https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/598221887682301/
Probably originally was 'works as designed' but now that the broadcast API is deprecated they will repurpose / enable / enhance